# what does the [i] mean in this section of code for python dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to know  if it means if the column 'CIG per day' and its index or is it treating '[i]' as another column?

```
cigarettes_by_smokers = []
for i in smokers:
     if df['cigsPerDay'][i] != 'nan':
        cigarettes_by_smokers.append(df['cigsPerDay'][i])
```

This is from a kaggle dataset. only asking as i tried to use this code and im still getting nan values in my data.

Comment: To answer this, we need to know what “smokers” is

Comment: Smokers is another dataframe created : smokers = df[df['currentSmoker'] == 1].index

Answer (score 0):

In this context [i] means every row in the df['cigsPerDay'] column. As you know df['cigsPerDay'] returns the whole column, to utilize a for loop and check every row in that column we use [i].

For better visualisation:

```
for i in range(3):

    d = {
    "one": pd.Series([1.0, 2.0, 3.0]),
    "two": pd.Series([10.0, 20.0, 30.0]),
    }

    df = pd.DataFrame(d)

    print(df['one'][i])
```

This code will result in:

```
1.0
2.0
3.0
```

In this code for loop will print every value in the df['one'] column.